How can I prevent Play Protect from scanning and reporting my app that I installed as an APK?
We have an app that is only used by end-users, and because it is installed as an APK, Play Protect displays a popup and wants to send a report. This is annoying for our customers. We install this app on our own screens, and since we produce thousands of these screens, manually disabling Play Protect is not feasible. How can I prevent this Play Protect popup using code? Our app is a native Android application written in Java.
We tried to disable Play Services using root commands, but it didn't work.

I had this problem too, unfortunately you just need to manually disable play protect on each device, there is no way to do it programmatically (or else every malicious app would just do it!)
Alternatively you can submit an appeal directly to Google but I'm not sure if that would work and it sounds like a lot of work.
